# Adiabatic switching, Gell-Mann and Low theorem and Moller operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, many-body, time-evolution, adiabatic

Consider the modified Hamiltonian
$$
H_{\eta}(t) = H_0 + e^{-\eta |t|} H_I
$$
where $\eta > 0$. Consider the interacting picture and the Moller operators obtained by the interaction picture time evolution operator
$$
\Omega^{(\pm)}_{\eta} = U_{I,\eta}(0, \pm \infty)
$$
then in these notes at page 665: http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/b6/psfiles/Chapter-8-scatter6.pdf it is given a proof of the fact that
$$
H_{\eta} \ \Omega^{(\pm)}_{\eta} = \Omega^{(\pm)}_{\eta} \ H_0
$$
Now in the interacting picture we can choose $|\psi(-\infty) \rangle_{I}$ to be an eigenstate of $H_0$ (since in the interaction picture we get time independent states at $t=\pm\infty$) and given the relation regarding the Moller operators we can prove that (also this is in the notes, same page)
$$
|\psi(0) \rangle_{I,\eta} = U_{I,\eta}(0,-\infty)|\psi(-\infty) \rangle_{I}
$$
is an eigenstate of $H_{\eta}(0)$ with the same energy of $|\psi(-\infty) \rangle_{I}$ (this result is actually showed also at page 61 of the Fetter and Walecka book, without any intelligible proof in my opinion). Now:

1) There is something wrong about this for me, $H_{\eta}(0)$ does not depend on $\eta$, while its eigenstate defined this way it does.

2) The proof of the Moller operators relation, formula (9.34) in the notes, it is given using the time independent Schroedinger evolution operator $e^{-iHt}$, which cannot be used in this case.

3) If this is true, we are obtaining a very similar result of the Gell-Mann and Low theorem, except for the fact we are not doing any limiting process on $\eta$, and we are getting the same energy when we reach $t=0$.
Also, at the end of page 670 of the notes, it says that Moller operators can carry free eigenstates from $t=-\infty$ into full hamiltonian eigenstates ad $t=0$ with different energy. And then uses the Gell-Man and Low theorem to prove this. What is the difference with before, only the fact that GL theorem tells information about the limiting process? What am I missing?

I think that I'm making some confusion because some of this result may be valid only making assumptions on the spectrum taken in consideration (discrete or continuum), but this is not clear to me.

I don't know if I've made myself clear enough, thank you by the way.

ps: I know that there is a similar question but I would like a more complete answer.

Comment: Nov 2023: Link now dead.